# Dúvida como validar compo com nome produto[], campo se trata de um array

Tags: jquery

Me deparei com a seguinte dúvida.

Estou utilizando o jQuery Validation Plugin v1.13.0 para validar meu formulário do lado do cliente.

Está funcionando, certinho.

mais o problema que não consigo resolver é tenho um campo com nome `produto[]`, o qual é uma array que envio varios campos com esse nome. posso enviar 1 como posso enviar 20 produtos.

```
data_emissao:   {required: true},
forma_pagamento:    {required: true},
produto[]:  {required: true}, // coloquei assim mais sem sucesso.
```

alguém já se deparou com esse problema?

Comment: Qual o problema que você está encontrando? ele não valida se tem ao menos 1 produto?

Comment: Não valida, esse campo produto[], na verdade se colocar produto[]:  {required: " "}, da erro nessa linha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para validar elementos do tipo `array`, coloque o nome do elemento em aspas simples nas regras de validação, exemplo:

**[Demo: JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pqpujjto/)**

```
$("#myform").validate({
    rules: {
        'produto[]': {
            required: true
        }
    }
});
```

---

#### EDIT

Sugestão de implementação utilizando [rules( “add”, rules )](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules#.22add.22rules):

**[Demo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pqpujjto/5/)**

**HTML**

```
<form id="myform">
    <label>
        <input type="text" name="produto[1]" class="produto"/>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="text" name="produto[2]" class="produto"/>
    </label>    
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

OBS: Os `names` dos `inputs` precisam ser únicos, no caso `produto[1],produto[2]` e etc.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#myform').validate({
        submitHandler: function (form) { 
            alert('formulário validado');
            form.submit();
        }
    });          
    /* faz loop por todos os elementos com classe produto
    * e adiciona nas regras para validação
    */
    $('input.produto').each(function () {
        $(this).rules('add', {
            required: true
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Abfurlan até valida, mais valida somente o primeiro campo produto[] os outros campos que adiciono depois não valida. esses campos são criados dinamicamente.

Comment: @ClaytonEduardoMergulhão Qual o tipo de `input` você está usando?

Comment: echo '<td><input type="text" name="produto[]" id="txtProduto_1" class="form-control input-xlarge"/></td>';

Comment: @ClaytonEduardoMergulhão editei com uma possível solução